# F# - Why FSharp.Data.SqlClient does not support views?

Tags: sql, f#, f#-data

I wonder if there is some deep underlying reason why `FSharp.Data.SqlClient` (https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/) does not support views. If the database is normalized, then very often I need to "grab" some columns from FK related tables in order to build some F# object in one go. It seems not right to create parameterless table functions just for this purpose. Views would do just fine but, unfortunately, FSharp.Data.SqlClient does not seem to support them :(

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't support views? Have you tried?

Comment: It does not: "SqlProgrammabilityProvider - quick access to Sql Server functions, stored procedures and tables in idiomatic F# way" - there is no mentioning of the views. And if you create a view, then it does not "see" it.

Comment: Ok, so it's just about `SqlProgrammabilityProvider` then? `FSharp.Data.SqlClient` contains more than just that, and I would think you should be able to use views with `SqlCommandProvider` at least. You might want to rephrase the question in that case.